# Dataset getChanges() method returns changes even when nothing is changed

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a `Dataset` in my form. I am using the `dataset.getchanges()` method to get changes in my dataset. It is always returning some change even if nothing is changed in the `Dataset`. I tried various methods to detect where the change is occurring, but was unsuccessful.
Please help me out.


Here's my code snippet

```
 Dim newds As DataSet
            newds = dss.GetChanges()
            MsgBox(newds.ToString())
            If newds IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim i As Integer = adap1.Update(newds, "dataview")
                If i > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show(i & " Record(s) Updated Sucessfully", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

                End If
```

Edit[1]: here's the `dss` code:

```
adap1 = New OleDbDataAdapter("select th.catalogue,th.name,pa.party_catalogue,pa.rate" _
                    & " from party_catalogue pa,itemhead th where pa.itemcode=th.itemcode and pa.party_code=" & a, conn)
        dss = New DataSet
        dss.Clear()
        adap1.Fill(dss, "dataview")

        DataGridView1.DataSource = dss.Tables(0)
```

Comment: First try PrintValues(newds, "Subset values") right after the call to GetChanges to see what is there. Also try adding parameters to GetChanges call :  DataRowState.Modified Or DataRowState.Added

Comment: Whenever a value is changed on a record, even if you set it to the same value it is now, it will change the rowstate. GetChanges just gets the records where the rowstate <> Unmodified. If you want to prevent this, you will have to go through each record returned and remove those where the Original and Current values are the same.

Comment: PrintValues - sorry, see that method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: But it is doing it in my case. It returns changes even if i just save existing records.

Comment: >>if i just save existing records...As Steve says, that may be a case of setting it to the same value, which changes the rowstate

Comment: Then how to avoid that.

Comment: Hard to say, since code for your variable dss is not included. As Steve says, you could go though each record and compare

Comment: wait. i'll give the dss code.

Comment: Got something new. it is updating the last row of the dataset again and again. that is why getting some changes. but why it is updating last row.?

Comment: Based on a comment above, you are getting changes, then saving them to the server and wondering why they still show changes? If so, sending records to be saved does NOT effect the records in memory. You must do something like `AcceptChanges` or clear the data and re-query it from the database.

Comment: But why it is updating last row even though i haven't selected that row for updation process.?

Comment: got something more new. it is by default updating 2nd row of the table if no row is explicitly updated. any specific reason for that.?